# DataTables Case Insensitive Search Issue

Tags: jquery, filter, datatable, datatables, case-insensitive

I'm using DataTables and jQuery to create a set of checkboxes to filter the table using the search box. This is implemented fully at http://www.lynden.com/about/brochures-test.html. Basically, when you select an option with the checkboxes, it'll take that option as a string and insert it in the DataTables search box. It works great, except for the fact that the caseInsensitive feature is just straight up not working when entering input into the search box without any prior filtering, which is weird. Weirder still is that when searching with "mi" it will pull up three results with the word Dynamic in them, but will totally ignore the Milky Way company category. Does anyone have any idea why it can sort of search case insensitively but ignores the beginnings of capitalized words?

```
    $('.dropdown-container')
.on('click', '.dropdown-button', function () {
    $('.dropdown-list').toggle();
})
.on('input', '.dropdown-search', function () {
    var target = $(this);
    var search = target.val().toLowerCase();
console.log(search);
    if (!search) {
        $('li').show();
        return false;
    }

    $('li').each(function () {
        var text = $(this).text().toLowerCase();
        var match = text.indexOf(search) > -1;
        $(this).toggle(match);
    });
})
.on('change', '[type="checkbox"]', function () {
    var numChecked = $('[type="checkbox"]:checked').length;
    $('.quantity').text(numChecked || 'Any');
});

$(document).ready(function () {
table = $('#brochure').DataTable({
    "search": {
"caseInsensitive": true
  },
    "pageLength": 25,
    "order": [
                [2, "desc"]
            ],
    "lengthMenu": [
                [25, 50, 75, -1],
                [25, 50, 75, "All"]
            ],
    "columnDefs": [{
        "targets": [2, 4, 5],
        "visible": false
            }]
});
var pID = location.search; //grab everything after and including the "?" in the URL
console.log(pID);
mloc = pID.indexOf("=") + 1; //identify the location of the actual value
pID = pID.slice(mloc) // captures the value of the parameter
table.search(pID, [1, 2, 3, 4], true, false, false, true).draw(); // assigns the parameter to the hidden input tag's value
})

function filter() {
//build a industry string 
var filters = $('input:checkbox[name="filter"]:checked').map(function ()    {
    return this.value;
}).get().join(' ');
console.log(filters);
//now filter in column 3, with a regular expression, no smart filtering, no inputbox, not case sensitive
table.search(filters, [1, 2, 3, 4], true, false, false, true).draw();
}
```

I'd love some help on this issue!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using [`search()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/search()) API method incorrectly. Apparently your initial incorrect call to `search()` causes the table to behave differently than configured.

You should be calling it as shown below:

```
table.search(pID).draw();
```

and

```
table.search(filters).draw();
```

Additional arguments for `search()` could be omitted because they enable "smart" and case insensitive search.

See [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/9mroezyv/1/) for code and demonstration.

Comment: @Naomi, your page looks great with those filters, great job!